# Javascript not loading in my Django + React Project with Vite.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, vite, vitest

So I had created a project with React as frontend and Django as it backend.

For the backend and frontend two separate folders were created : `backend` and `frontends` (ignore the spelling mistake it was intentional).

I created a react project using vite.js and also created a build production by using the `npm run build` command.

I then linked the `dist` folder which was generated to django through `settings.py` along with all other configurations needed for linking static files and stuff, editing `views.py` as well as `urls.py`. Below is the syntax for my `STATICFILES_DIRS`

```
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(REAL_BASE_DIR,'frontends', 'dist', 'assets'),]
```

Also the directory tree of my project :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbe84.png)

So when I start the django server the static files successfully load (like the javascript and the .css) and its show `200 Success CODE` and no `404` but in the console of my browser the following error shows up particularly for the Javascript file (not the css).
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuwJw.png)

The CSS file loads successfully with no errors but the Javascript file shows the above error and I can't find any possible solution on how to fix it.

Expecting the JavaScript file to load since there were no `404 Not found` errors in logs of Django.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for set up **STATICFILES_DIRS**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```

and for set up **STATIC_ROOT**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

you need to run the **collectstatic** management command, Django will copy all static files from all the directories specified in **STATICFILES_DIRS** to the directory specified in **STATIC_ROOT**.

Comment: But I do not have any folder called static though. All the static files which are generated by react's build command are stored in a separate folder called `frontends/dist/assets` (situated outside my backend folder) so that's why  in STATICFILES_DIRS I provided that path. Then how will it search for the static files if the folder doesn't exist.

Comment: I mean to say that you have assigned this STATICFILES_DIRS in different way. You need to change the brackets syntax, see my code below:-

Your code 
`STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(REAL_BASE_DIR,'frontends', 'dist', 'assets'),)`

My code 
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(REAL_BASE_DIR,'frontends', 'dist', 'assets'),]`

Comment: I followed your steps. First I changed the brackets of `STATICFILES_DIRS` to `[ ]` then I pasted:
`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(REAL_BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`
then I ran `py manage.py collectstatic` , it successfully ran and created a `staticfiles` folder in the root of my project.

then ran the server to test but I am still getting the same error of 

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Comment: Here's the settings.py snippet after making the changes you mentioned 
https://imgur.com/a/2qMtCJ8

Comment: One possible reason for this error is that the server is not configured to serve JavaScript module scripts with the correct MIME type. To fix this, you can add the following line to your server configuration file:  `AddType application/javascript .mjs` 
            . This tells the server to serve .mjs files (which are used for JavaScript modules) with the correct MIME type.

Comment: I found something rather interesting. I tried to open the website using Microsoft Edge and it started working! But in google chrome it is showing the error I was talking about. Quite weird tbh and I will try search for more solutions on how to fix this error for Google Chrome.